# Correct preposition for "porch"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I would like to know whether 'I park my car '***on*** the porch' or '***in*** the porch' is correct?

Comment: I heartily recommend that you do neither.

Comment: I guess that if there is not enough space under the porch, then this question is NARQ.

Comment: A porch is usually a flat place so you would park -on- it. If it were an enclosed place you could park -in- it (because you normally park your car -in- the garage but -on- the driveway.

Comment: I suspect that, at least for Americans, the architectural feature you wish to refer to is a _carport_, and, since it a carport (in contrast to a garage) is open, the preposition is _on_.

Comment: @Andrew: All good, except we don't park _on_ the carport, we park _in_ it, or _under_ it.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, it's neither ***on*** nor ***in*** the porch. This is a decent-sized porch:

[image: Wooden porch from Roger Gladwell] [Source](http://www.rogergladwell.co.uk/20dec06/porch.html)

Parking on that is plainly ridiculous; and it's too small to park a car in it.

Andrew Lazarus suggested a carport, and it could look like a porch:

[image: Carport in front of garages] [[Andreas Hornig](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carport_In_Front_Of_Garages.jpg)]

In British English, one parks ***under*** a carport; and if this structure were called a porch, it would still be ***under*** the porch. It's *under* because there is simply a supported roof, and no walls to be inside of.

What British English doesn't have is "porch" describing the sort of large covered terrace which fronts some American houses.

Comment: I suppose one might conceivably albeit somewhat metaphorically park oneself on the porch, if one were a weary pedestrian awaiting the owner’s return.  I have heard it used colloquially that way.

Comment: Hm, you know what?  That is actually not a porch, because it is level with the patio.  In might be stretched to be an entryway — maybe. For some reason, I feel like a porch needs to involve a different level, maybe a different flooring, and probably a step or two. Does that sound odd to you?

Comment: It's a British porch. A difference in level is not required here. Although this one does actually have a different flooring.

Comment: Odd.  Take a gander [at these](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=porch&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi). Don’t those look more like porches to you than what you showed? Plus you can park bikes on them, although not cars one would hope. :) (Though it might stand to wonder whether in its infinite wisdom, Google Images may produce only British porches for you and American ones for me.)

Comment: @tchrist: Yup, your link shows this picture in first place for me. It's bewitched, I tell you.

Answer (score 0):

**On** the porch is correct. Unless there's a secret compartment/garage underneath your porch, on is the correct word. **In** would mean that the porch **surrounds** the car in some way.

Comment: Yes, but at least in the US, a porch is not where you'd park a car.  A porch is the landing outside of a door into the house where people stand while waiting to go in. Some people often will have a small sitting area on their porch and maybe a porch swing.

Comment: @Jim: What you're saying here is usually correct, of course, although I'll mention that there's a house in our neighborhood with a built-in garage beneath the porch/patio. I haven't seen that too often, though. Still, even allowing for [this architecture](http://imagesus.homeaway.com/mda01/502338ac-a832-48ca-b5c1-beb6907e1a82.1.12), I'd use _under_, not _in_ or _on_.

Comment: In my variety of American English, porches are for people to perch on, period. If it's not grass and it's large enough to park a car on, it's a driveway, a patio, or some other local term.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, go ahead and forget the idea of parking a car on the porch, unless it is a toy car. You park your bike on the porch but your car in the garage.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in parts of the US,  the carport is referred to as the Car porch.  In that case, yes you do Park on the car porch.  It actually makes sense.  A porch for the car.